# BufWriteCmd handler

Tags: vim

What key parts would I have to use, to get the `foo()` function write the buffer to disk in this case (default behavior)? Especially the vim part, be it via `vim.eval()` or `vim.command()` or whatever.

```
au  BufWriteCmd * exec :python foo()
```

`foo()`:

```
def foo():
    abuf = vim.eval("expand('<abuf>')"
```

Comment: What is “exec” doing in the first line of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
au  BufWriteCmd * :python foo()

python << EOF
import vim, os
def foo():
    abuf=int(vim.eval('expand("<abuf>")'))-1
    amatch=vim.eval('expand("<amatch>")')
    abang=bool(int(vim.eval('v:cmdbang')))
    cmdarg=vim.eval('v:cmdarg')

    if os.path.isdir(amatch):
        raise ValueError('Cannot write to directory {0}'.format(amatch))
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(amatch)):
        raise ValueError('Directory {0} does not exist'.format(amatch))

    encoding=vim.eval('&encoding')

    opts={l[0] : l[1] if len(l)>1 else True
          for l in [s[2:].split('=')
                    for s in cmdarg.split()]}
    if 'ff' not in opts:
        opts['ff']=vim.eval('getbufvar({0}, "&fileformat")'.format(abuf))
        if not opts['ff']:
            opts['ff']='unix'
    if 'enc' not in opts:
        opts['enc']=vim.eval('getbufvar({0}, "&fileencoding")'.format(abuf))
        if not opts['enc']:
            opts['enc']=encoding
    if 'nobin' in opts:
        opts['bin']=False
    elif 'bin' not in opts:
        opts['bin']=vim.eval('getbufvar({0}, "&binary")'.format(abuf))

    if opts['bin']:
        opts['ff']='unix'
        eol=bool(int(vim.eval('getbufvar({0}, "&endofline")'.format(abuf))))
    else:
        eol=True

    eolbytes={'unix': '\n', 'dos': '\r\n', 'mac': '\r'}[opts['ff']]

    buf=vim.buffers[abuf]
    f=open(amatch, 'wb')
    first=True
    for line in buf:
        if opts['enc']!=encoding:
            # Does not handle invalid bytes.
            line=line.decode(encoding).encode(opts['enc'])
        if not first:
            f.write(eolbytes)
        else:
            first=False
        f.write(line)
    if eol:
        f.write(eolbytes)
    f.close()
EOF
```

With the above code you will have almost complete emulation of standard `:w smth` behavior.

Comment: Is it a mistake in the loop where you iterate the lines in the buffer and append a new line only after the first line? Anyway I've got the point, `eolbytes` has to be added at the end of file only if `eol` is true (and the file can contain only one line). So great answer, thanks.

Comment: @Flavius No, it is not a mistake: I first do `f.write(eolbytes)` and then `f.write(line)`. I prepend new line, not append it because it is easier to implement then checking for processed line being a last one. Though you may refer to it as “appending after the previous line”.

Comment: Oh I missed that part (the `not` in `not first`).